# Querying multiple values from multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query by a list of value pair.

For example:

```
src   dst   byte
 a     b     16
 c     d     20
 e     f     50
 a     f      0
```

I want to query by `src` and `dst` in one Query to get `(a, b, 16)` and `(e, f, 50)`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE src IN ( a, e )
AND dst IN (b, f )
```

But this statement also gives me `(a, f, 0)`.

Is it possible to get `(a, b, 16)` and `(e, f, 50)` in one query?

Comment: have you got your expected answer?

Comment: I am wondering if there is any other method besides 
WHERE src = 'a' AND dst = 'b'
OR    src = 'e' AND dst = 'f'?

Comment: What you want other? give example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE src = 'a' AND dst = 'b'
   OR src = 'e' AND dst = 'f'
```

Comment: Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1):

Do simple things like

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE (src = 'a' AND dst = 'b')
   OR (src = 'e' AND dst = 'f');
```